# ERROR 2616 Numeric overflow during computation while doing count(*)

Tags: sql, teradata

I am trying to do a `select count(*)` from table from a table and I am not able to do it because of this error. I am not aware of the number of rows in the table.

I am not doing any other aggregation in my query apart from this.

I guess it has something to do with the count value which is too large to be stored in INTEGER.

What is the alternative?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When your session runs in Teradata mode the result of a COUNT is INTEGER as you already noticed (in ANSI mode it will be a DECIMAL with at least 15 digits).

The workaround is simple, cast it to a bigint:

```
SELECT CAST(COUNT(*) AS BIGINT)...
```

Comment: I really wish Teradata mode would move up to BIGINT if they aren't going to fully comply with ANSI. Just like I wish Excel wouldn't choke on DECIMAL(18,0) or larger. :)

Comment: ANSI doesn't talk about numeric precision, this is always "implementation-defined".  If you want better compliance with ANSI you just have to switch session mode to ANSI.  And Excel already chokes on DEC(16) as it's storing/processing everything as FLOAT :-)

Comment: No thank you. I'm quite content with the subtleties of Teradata mode. :)

Answer (score 2):

This is the #2 Google hit for Teradata 2616, so I want to add something.  If you're getting 2616 "Numeric overflow occured" from a SUM in Teradata, the solution is to CAST, then SUM.  The CAST has to be inside the SUM:

SELECT
SUM(CAST(WHATEVER_QTY  AS   DECIMAL(38,0)))
FROM
TER_DATABASE.WHATEVER_TABLE  ;

In my case, DECIMAL(38,0) worked, but BIGINT was 2616.  You are welcome to experiment.  Here's the link at info.teradata:

http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_14_00/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1145_111A/Data_Type_Conversions.098.297.html

Comment: lol back on Teradata and just got saved by my own StackOverflow from 9 years ago. I should have emphasized that the CAST has to be DECIMAL(38,0) <--- NOT integer